# Javascript window.open not firing on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, onchange, window.open

I've been looking everywhere for an answer all over but I can't find anything that works. 
It works fine on all of my browsers but doesn't work on mobile devices. I'd like to have the links open in a new tab if possible.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's what I have:

```
<form name="dropdownForm" method="POST" action="" >
<select name="dropdown" id="myform" onchange="document.getElementById('form').setAttribute('action', this.value); document.dropdownForm.submit(); if (this.value);">     
<option value="">Choose</option>     
<option value="http://www.mywebsite2.com" name="My Website 1">1</option>     
<option value="http://www.mywebsite2.com" name="My Website 2">2</option>     
<option value="http://www.mywebsite3.com" name="My Website 3">3</option>     
<option value="http://www.mywebsite4.com" name="My Website 4">4</option>     
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myform").onchange = function() {

var openNewTab = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    if (this.selectedIndex!==0 && openNewTab.substring(0,4) == "http") {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Home', 'Clicks', this.value);
        window.open(this.value, '_blank');
    } 
};
</script>
```

Comment: Which mobile/browser?

Comment: `window.open` is not JQuery method, it is pure javascript method. Check documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: @ChrisBenseler I'm testing it on Safari (iphone/ipad) It's not working. How can I make this work?

Comment: Why are you using a dropdown for navigation when anchor tags work much better?